# Finding Sources or Citations for Theorems

Tags: calculus, probability, discrete-mathematics

I just started writing math papers, and I'm finding I often use existing theorems or statements in mathematics without knowing who to cite. Often times the theorems I'm using don't have a clear source, and figuring out who developed them is quite challenging. Is there something I'm missing? Is there some trick or streamlined method of getting this information that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many (most) results aren't named, so often you can just point to any one source that has them - maybe a text that you learned it from or another paper you've read. If it's used but not proven in another paper, then hopefully those authors will point towards an original source. If you don't know where it comes from, try looking in papers that proved similar results to yours, or used a similar technique.

Also, sometimes a result is considered sufficiently trivial in the discipline/sub-discipline that its basically taken for granted and authors assume everyone knows. I have found it difficult to tell whether I should prove something by hand or take it for granted, especially in areas which are not my primary interest. In that case I tend to err on the side of caution try to find where the result has been used, and failing that include a brief proof (often in an appendix).